# Google Apps Script Javascript compatibility error

Tags: google-apps-script, javascript

I have successfully created [some code to extract data from a 2D array using A1 notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58545538/367032). Handy to avoid multiple calls to GAS services whit ordinary `getRange` calls.

While the code perfectly works in javascript, it throws an error in Google Apps Script upon saving.

The offending code is:

```
return matrix.slice(startRow, endRow + 1).map(i => i.slice(startCol, endCol + 1))
```

GAS seems rejecting code in the `.map` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Google Apps Script now offers two JavaScript engines

- Original: Based in Mozilla's Rhino JavaScript interpreter, which doesn't support several ECMAScript 5 features
- New: Google V8, used by Chrome and Node.js, which support ECMAScript 6 but with some limitations (i.e. it doesn't support modules)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#february_5_2020
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

---

Your code is using an arrow function. This feature is part of ECMAScript 6 but it's not supported by default by Google Apps Script (it supports some ECMAScript 5 features but not all). Replace the arrow function by an anonymous function, add the arrow function polyfill use CLASP a desktop IDE and Babel or something similar.

References

- [Basic JavaScript Features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/?hl=en#basic_javascript_features)
- [Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252409/1595451)