# can't locate ; syntax error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm writing a function to calculate the income tax burden in the UK, and the Google Apps Script page keeps giving me an error notice that there's a missing semicolon (*Missing ; before statement. (line 27, file "Code")*). This code runs fine in my browser's javscript console and I can't seem to find why AppScript doesn't like it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
function apply_reliefs(amount, reliefs) {
  /**
   * Make some logic here to decrease the taxable amount
   */
  return amount;
};

function apply_allowances(amount, allowances) {
  /**
   * Make some logic here to decrease the taxable amount
   */
  return amount;
};


/**
 * Returns the taxes owed given the income earned for a year and the reliefs and allowances. 
 *
 * @param {income} income The GROSS income for the year.
 * @param {[allowances]} opt_allowances A string of alowances codes
 * @param {[reliefs]} opt_reliefs A string of relief codes
 * @return The taxes owed on the income earned.
 * @customfunction
 */
function brittax(income, opt_allowances, opt_reliefs) {
  // FYI: the next line is line 27:
  let allowances = opt_allowances;
  let reliefs = opt_reliefs;

  if(null == allowances) {
    allowances = "";
  }

  if(null == reliefs) {
    reliefs = "";
  }

  let amount = apply_reliefs(income, reliefs);
  amount = apply_allowances(amount, allowances);

  //  Band                Taxable income        Tax rate
  //  Personal Allowance  Up to £12,500           0%
  //  Basic rate          £12,501 to £50,000     20%
  //  Higher rate         £50,001 to £150,000    40%
  //  Additional rate     over £150,000          45%


  let brackets = [
    { limit: 12500, rate: 0 },
    { limit: 50000, rate: 0.2},
    { limit: 150000, rate: 0.4},
    { limit: null, rate: 0.45}
  ];

  let tax = 0;

  for (const bracket of brackets) {
    if(null == bracket.limit) {
      tax += amount * bracket.rate;
    } else {
      tax += Math.min(bracket.limit, amount) * bracket.rate;
      amount -= bracket.limit;
    }

    if(amount <= 0) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return tax;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script doesn't support `let`

Related

- [Google Apps Script Javascript compatibility error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135859/88163)

Reference

- [Basic JavaScript Features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/?hl=en#basic_javascript_features)