# Yield in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a generator as part of a script that I am writing. I am getting syntax errors. I am starting to wonder if it is because it is a new feature of JavaScript that is not in Google App Scripts.

Is this the case? If so, is there another way to create generators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script Javascript compatibility error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135859/google-apps-script-javascript-compatibility-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script doesn't support `yield` / `generators`

Related

- [Google Apps Script Javascript compatibility error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135859/88163)
- [can't locate ; syntax error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136586/88163)

Reference

- [Basic JavaScript Features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/?hl=en#basic_javascript_features)

Comment: See the update made to my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135862/88163) to  [Google Apps Script Javascript compatibility error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135859/88163)