# Google Script Fails to Return Boolean Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to create a simple function that returns a boolean value when the word "website" appears in a specific cell. When I run the debugger, `matches` returns undefined.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = ss.getRange(8,1).getValue().toString(); 
  var matches = url.includes("website");
  return matches; 
}
```

Why doesn't my function return a boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't returns a boolean because Google Apps Script doesn't support `String.prototype.includes()` in the same way that it doesn't support several of the additions introduced in ECMAScript 2015

Related

- [Google Apps Script Javascript compatibility error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135859/88163)
- [can't locate ; syntax error](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136586/88163)

Reference

- [Basic JavaScript Features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/?hl=en#basic_javascript_features)

Comment: I found out how to accomplish what I wanted without ECMAScript 2015 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: @JulianMartinez Please post a summary of your finding as an to your question.